# Is there any way to execute Textbox UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus before Lost Focus Event?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, lost-focus, updatesourcetrigger

I have a `TextBox` of which the `Text` property must be updated *before* executing the `LostFocus` event, because in the `LostFocus` event I use the values of the `Text` property for calculations.

Currently when entering the `LostFocus` event (`txtTotaisNfe_LostFocus`) the `ThisDataContext.DescontoTotal` has not yet had its value updated.

**P.S:** I cannot use `UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged` because I use a converter (`PriceConverter1`) in WPF that can only be executed after I have entered the complete value in the `TextBox`. It converts the entered value into 2 decimal cases value (that is, when running `LostFocus`).

**The question is:** Is there any way in the .NET process queue to understand that it must *first* run the `LostFocus` from `UpdateSourceTrigger` *and then* the `LostFocus` (`txtTotaisNfe_LostFocus`)?

WPF Code `(DescontoTotal = ThisDataContext.Desconto)`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DescontoTotal, Converter={StaticResource PriceConverter1}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" LostFocus="txtTotaisNfe_LostFocus"/>
```

`LostFocus` Event Code:

```
private void txtTotaisNfe_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Rateia o Total de Desconto da NFe entre os Produtos.
    foreach (var item in _lsProdutos)
    {
        item.Desconto = (ThisDataContext.DescontoTotal / ThisDataContext.TotalProdutos * item.ValorProduto).Round();
    }
}
```

PriceConverter1 Code (Please ignore Best Practices in this):

```
public class PriceConverter1 : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    return ((decimal)value).ToString("##,###,##0.00");
                }
                catch
                {
                    return "0.00";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "0.00";
            }
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string price = value.ToString();

            decimal result;
            if (decimal.TryParse(price, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, null, out result))
            {
                return result;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using events directly is messy. You can workaround it by queueing something via dispatcher, but in general take a look at MVVM, separate view and view model, use bindings/commands and don't put any calculations into the view.

Comment: Since you're already binding, why are you using an event such as lostfocus at all? When the user tabs out, the value will transfer to the viewmodel. Use a validation rule on your binding or just validate before you use it for calculations f you're concerned about validation.

Comment: You're not need to execute code in Event handler here. You may do it in `DescontoTotal` setter instead. Binding makes you free from using Event handlers at all. And remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` then. [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern)

Comment: usually stuff like that is not done with events but by using the setter of the property you bound too. for example in your case the `DescontoTotal` property.